# Judge the convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1/\sqrt{n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to judge the convergence of the sequence?
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$

#### Context

I know two methods to judge whether a series converes: one is to calculate $\lim \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_{n}}$, the other is to calculate  $\lim u_n^{1/n}$, but it seems they all equal to $1$.

Comment: Have you learned the integral test? Or p-test?

Comment: $\dfrac{1}{n}\le\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: @Petaro I know two method to judge whether a summation is converge. one is to calculate $\lim \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_{n}}$, the other is to calculate  $\lim n^{1/n}$, but it seems they all equal to 1

Comment: @Zircht Thanks, I see

Answer (score 2):

First you need to restrict the domain of your series since $n=0$ results in division by $0$.

Second, recall that the harmonic series, $\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ diverges. Since $\frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \text{ for } n\geq 1$ it follows by the comparison test that the series $\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ diverges.

Answer (score 2):

$$  \sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+...\\now\\consider\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \\  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \\ ...\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\\now\\sum\\of\\them\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+...\geq n*\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt{n}=\frac{\sqrt{n^2} }{\sqrt{n}}\\so \\\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\geq \sqrt{n}  $$

Comment: You mean $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{k}}\geq\sqrt{n}$?

Comment: no , right side contains n time of sqrt(1/n) , so I simplify that to sqrt(n)

Comment: Yes, but you can't use $n$ both in the RHS and as running variable in the sum!